# iOS check non-default open ports

Tags: ios, networking, jailbreak, ssh

Trying to implement a JB check for non-default open ports (i.e., 22/TCP SSH):

```
/**
 Checks for non-standard ports
 */
inline int isPortOpen(short port)__attribute__((always_inline));
-(BOOL)isPortOpen:(short) port
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &addr.sin_addr)) {
        int result = connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

        // error :(
        int w00t = errno;
        NSLog(@"Error: %i",w00t);

        if(result == 0){
            NSLog(@"FAILED JB CHECK -- non-standard port open!");
            return YES;
        }
        close(sock);
    }

    NSLog(@"PASSED JB CHECK -- non-standard ports closed.");
    return NO;
}
```

But `connect()` fails (`result` is -1) and the `errno` is 1 -- `EPERM`
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/intro.2.html

> 1 EPERM Operation not permitted.  An attempt was made to perform an operation
>                 limited to processes with appropriate privileges or to the
>                 owner of a file or other resources.

Looking at the manual for `connect()`, `EPERM` is not one of the possible return errors.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/connect.2.html

So, the only reason I can see for getting `EPERM` is the sandbox, but:

1. Running on a jailbroken iPod (iOS 8.4)
2. The container seatbelt profile allows outbound network connections by default

I'd like to understand what's happening. Note that I've tried connecting to the wireless interface as well, instead of loopback.

Comment: 22 is a system port - range from 0 to 1023 are well-known or system ports. Looks like sandbox doesn't allow you to connect to them. As I understand that code is executed inside sandboxed AppStore-like application? Also, if it's a sandbox violation it probably will be printed in the console.

Comment: I'm sure that'd be the case if I was trying to listen at 22, but I'm just trying to connect... If that was the case we wouldn't be able to connect to port 80, or 443 as well... (for example) I'll check the console for anything helpful though!

Comment: That's different - you're trying to connect to those ports through loopback interface - that's not common. Normal connections a made from the outside, so no sandboxing is involved. It would make sense for Apple to restrict that kind of connections.

Comment: OK, I guess I should've added I've tried connecting to the wireless interface as well

Comment: As far as I know it will still go through loopback interface. And IP address on your side is still 127.0.0.1. So it's still possible to detect what you're doing

Comment: tbh, I think you might be right, but this is a check straight from the MAHH and just seems unlikely @domchell would put a check in there that would violate the container profile :/

Comment: Apple constantly adds new sandbox restrictions so it might work on older versions but not on the new ones. How old is the post you're referring to?

Comment: sorry @creker I was away for a few days. I was saying the code was taken directly from the Mobile Application Hacker's Handbook, a (relatively recent) book on mobile application security.